# Call functions in an event/function chain?

Tags: c#

I have 3 functions. They can be called in any order (later they may need specific order).
The return value of one function should be the first param of the next. How do i do this? what i am thinking is something like the below. Whats the best way to do this?

```
string void fn(string sz, data d, eventhdl nextFunc)
{
    //do stuff
    if(nextFunc == null)
        return ret;
    else
        return nextFunc(ret, d, nextFunc.Next);
}
```

Comment: What you have is called a continuation, and is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple methods to participate in a single request.  Order matters.  I think you might have yourself a [Decorator](http://www.netobjectives.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=TheDecoratorPattern) pattern in your problem.  It's hard to tell working backward from implementation, though.  It might be a [Chain of Responsibility](http://www.netobjectives.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=TheChainOfResponsibilityPattern) if you are trying to route a request to the *right* function.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
T Foo<T>(T seed, IEnumerable<Func<T, T>> funcs)
{
    T current = seed;

    foreach (Func<T, T> func in funcs)
    {
        current = func(current);
    }

    return current;
}
```

Usage:

```
int result = Foo<int>(1, new Func<int, int>[]
             {
                 i => i + 1,
                 i => i * 2,
                 i => i * i
             });

// result is 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a class `ComboFunc` with a fluent interface on it so you can do ...

var fn = new ComboFunc().A("arg1").B("arg2").C("arg3");
var result = fn.Apply("arg4");

The fluent interface on class ComboFunc can be used to build up the function chain internally which you then execute.  B() for example would chain function b() onto the Func chain internally and return a new ComboFunc() object.

This gives you 
(a) clean syntax; 
(b) the ability to specify rules that constrain **AT DESIGN TIME** which functions can be called on top of which others (by returning a different type.

Something like ...

```
    public abstract class ComboFuncBase
    {
        protected Func<string,string> chain = x => x;     // start with identity operation

        // Here are your various functions ... defined as methods or as functions like this ..
        protected Func<string, string> Afunc = input => input + "A";
        protected Func<string, string> Bfunc = input => input + "B";
        protected Func<string, string> Cfunc = input => input + "C";

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute the chain of functions
        /// </summary>
        public string Apply(string argument)
        {
            return chain(argument);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply FunctionC - always available
        /// </summary>
        public ComboFuncWithC C(string sz)
        {
            return new ComboFuncWithC() { chain = x => Cfunc(chain(x)) };
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A chain without a C in it yet allows A's and B's
    /// </summary>
    public class ComboFunc : ComboFuncBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Apply FunctionA
        /// </summary>
        public ComboFunc A(string sz)
        {
            return new ComboFunc() { chain = x => Afunc(chain(x)) };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Apply FunctionB
        /// </summary>
        public ComboFunc B(string sz)
        {
            return new ComboFunc() { chain = x => Bfunc(chain(x)) };
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// After C has been applied you can't apply A or B
    /// </summary>
    public class ComboFuncWithC : ComboFuncBase
    {
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "hello";

        var combo = new ComboFunc().A(" world").B("!").C(" - see");

        // Intellisense / Compiler will not allow this ...
        //var combo2 = new ComboFuncBase.ComboFunc().A(" world").C("!").B(" - see");
```

Comment: You seem like you like functional programming (there like no list, everything is chained etc). I am not saying anything bad but this looks like its overdesign. I dont see any problems but its doing more then it needs to do (ATM i am using param Type[] and a foreach loop. Additional note every function is a static function.

Comment: The Functions Afunc, Bfunc, ... can be defined as static methods if you like ... no other changes needed.

Comment: You could also build up a list of functions to call within the class but you'd just end up calling the same nested function calls at the end, it's less code to build it as you go.  This approach also means you can vary the parameter types, so Cfunc could take an int, Bfunc a list, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FunctionCaller
{
    class Demo
    {
        private class data { }

        delegate string OperationDelegate(string sz, data d, Queue<OperationDelegate> funcs);

        public void CallFunctions()
        {
            var funcs = new Queue<OperationDelegate>();
            funcs.Enqueue(fn1);
            funcs.Enqueue(fn2);
            funcs.Enqueue(fn3);
            data d = new data();
            string sz = "Start";

            string result = CallFuncChain(sz, d, funcs);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static string CallFuncChain(string sz, data d, Queue<OperationDelegate> funcs)
        {
            if (funcs.Count > 0)
            {
                OperationDelegate nextFunc = funcs.Dequeue();
                sz = nextFunc(sz, d, funcs);
            }
            return sz;
        }

        string fn1(string sz, data d, Queue<OperationDelegate> funcs)
        {
            string ret = sz + "\r\nfn1";
            ret = CallFuncChain(ret, d, funcs);
            return ret;
        }

        string fn2(string sz, data d, Queue<OperationDelegate> funcs)
        {
            string ret = sz + "\r\nfn2";
            ret = CallFuncChain(ret, d, funcs);
            return ret;
        }

        string fn3(string sz, data d, Queue<OperationDelegate> funcs)
        {
            string ret = sz + "\r\nfn3";
            ret = CallFuncChain(ret, d, funcs);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is basically an implementation of my question. I was hoping someone could tell me a premade CallFuncChain. I guess it doesnt exist. I think i'll accept this answer.

Comment: How will this enforce the order in which you can apply the functions?

Comment: Can you use a more OO approach, such as the Visitor pattern? I know it's not premade, but that way you can make an object tree which contains one object per function (one object per behaviour) but which can contain other objects. I'd be happy to post a sample if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you don't want to use your own CallFuncChain, there is an alternative using Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace FunctionCaller
{
    class Demo2
    {
        private class data { }

        public void CallFunctions()
        {
            var funcs = new Func<string, data, string>[] { 
                fn1, fn2, fn3
            };

            data d = new data();

            string sz1 = "Start";

            string result = funcs.Aggregate(
                sz1,
                (sz, x) => x(sz, d)
            );

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        string fn1(string sz, data d)
        {
            return sz + "\r\nfn1";
        }


        string fn2(string sz, data d)
        {
            return sz + "\r\nfn2";
        }

        string fn3(string sz, data d)
        {
            return sz + "\r\nfn3";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit uneasy about this, although it's clean... Linq lets us do many things with functions which I sometimes think "should" be done with objects instead.